# Remove background from image using python:The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, image-processing

i tried to build a function that take an image, and remove specific pixel values from it:

```
def background_remove(img):
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            if img[i, j] == 0:
                img[i,j] = 1
    return img
```

when i compile i have this error:

```
     if img[i, j] == 0:
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely, `img` is some multi-channel image. Then, your comparison will fail as shown. Force `img` to be single-channel (e.g. grayscale), then your code will work.

Comment: HansHirse  you are right, i make "as_gray=True" and it work, thankyou